Three matched ID# columns in a single dataframe one of them has NAs that I need to fill in using the existing data in R
I combined two dataframes using two different shared ID columns ("name" and "idA"). One of the datasets had a third ID column that was retained ("idB"). Now I have one dataframe with all three IDs (name, idA, idB,) per individual/case that need to match.
Columns "name" and "idA" matching equals a unique individual/case and this is a long format dataframe so there are multiple observations per case. Column "idB" now has NA values due to it being added to data that did not have the column originally.
I need to replace NA using the other cases in the existing data based on the condition that "name" and "idA" match and have a value for "idB". If there is a case that has NA for "idB" and no match between "name" and "idA" in the existing dataframe then "idB" should stay as NA.
I tried a tidyverse solution using group_by() and mutate():
df1_rev <- df1 %>%
  group_by(name, idA) %>%
  mutate(idB = unique(idB[!is.na(idB)]))

which did nothing. When I use it with my actual dataset (which has true identifiers so I can't post here) I get the error below ("XXXX" represents actual names and SSNs of people):

Error in mutate():
ℹ In argument: idB = unique(idB[!is.na(idB)]).
ℹ In group 2: name = "XXXX" and idA = "XXXX".
Caused by error:
! idB must be size 1, not 0.

Not sure if this matters but the class of my actual dataset and example dataset is different:

Class of example data: "data.table" "data.frame"
Class of actual data: "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"

Here is an example of what I have:
df1 <- data.frame(
  name = c("Sachin","Sachin","Sourav","Sourav","Dravid", "Sehwag", "Dhoni", "Ronin",   "Ronin", "Paul", "jorge", "Anke", "Krystal", "Katy", "Katy","Josh", "Paul"),
  idA = c("1234", "1234", "9876", "9876", "3456", "8888", "4032", "1093", "1093", "3452", "3332", "7656", "0023", "4244", "4244","4244","1111"),
  idB = c(1,"NA",2,2,3,"NA",5,6,"NA","NA",8,9,10,"NA",11,"NA","NA"),
  var_a = c(4,5,1.6,4.4,2,2,4,9,2,34,5,6,7,2,0,4,8),
  var_b = c("d","h","g","w","g","p","ads","f","a","iu","n","lag", "lo", "t", "v","y","k"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

Here is what I want:
df1_rev <- data.frame(
  name = c("Sachin","Sachin","Sourav","Sourav","Dravid", "Sehwag", "Dhoni", "Ronin", "Ronin", "Paul", "jorge", "Anke", "Krystal", "Katy", "Katy","Josh","Paul"),
  idA = c("1234", "1234", "9876", "9876", "3456", "8888", "4032", "1093", "1093", "3452", "3332", "7656", "0023", "4244", "4244","4244","1111"),
  idB = c(1,1,2,2,3,"NA",5,6,6,"NA",8,9,10,11,11,"NA","NA"),
  var_a = c(4,5,1.6,4.4,2,2,4,9,2,34,5,6,7,2,0,4,8),
  var_b = c("d","h","g","w","g","p","ads","f","a","iu","n","lag", "lo", "t", "v","y","k"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


You can use tidyr::fill(). Based on your sample df1, you first need to convert your string "NA" values to NA. It looks like your idB column is supposed to be integer, so this will accommodate that too.
If the idB values need to remain as strings, simply remove as.integer(). Assuming your real dataset contains true NAs, you can omit the mutate() line completely.
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1_rev <- df1 |>
  mutate(idB = as.integer(na_if(idB, "NA"))) |>
  group_by(name, idA) |>
  fill(idB, .direction = "downup") |>
  ungroup()

df1_rev
# # A tibble: 17 × 5
#    name    idA     idB var_a var_b
#    <chr>   <chr> <int> <dbl> <chr>
#  1 Sachin  1234      1   4   d    
#  2 Sachin  1234      1   5   h    
#  3 Sourav  9876      2   1.6 g    
#  4 Sourav  9876      2   4.4 w    
#  5 Dravid  3456      3   2   g    
#  6 Sehwag  8888     NA   2   p    
#  7 Dhoni   4032      5   4   ads  
#  8 Ronin   1093      6   9   f    
#  9 Ronin   1093      6   2   a    
# 10 Paul    3452     NA  34   iu   
# 11 jorge   3332      8   5   n    
# 12 Anke    7656      9   6   lag  
# 13 Krystal 0023     10   7   lo   
# 14 Katy    4244     11   2   t    
# 15 Katy    4244     11   0   v    
# 16 Josh    4244     NA   4   y    
# 17 Paul    1111     NA   8   k

Based on your comment, to avoid having to do it manually you can check if any individuals with more than one record have more than one idB value (e.g. NA and another value) by using:
df1_rev |>
  group_by(name, idA) |>
  filter(n() > 1 & n_distinct(idB) > 1)
# A tibble: 0 × 5
# Groups:   name, idA [0]
# ℹ 5 variables: name <chr>, idA <chr>, idB <int>, var_a <dbl>, var_b <chr>

If no rows are returned, then the code has worked as expected.

@L Tyrone I'm still doing some manual double checking but I believe this worked perfectly thank you!!

@mchuck - updated the answer with a method to save you having to manually check.

@L Tyrone - worked like a charm thanks again!!

If the order of the rows does not matter, you can use the fill() function from tidyr after sorting the data by name and idA.
library(tidyverse)
df1 <- data.frame( name = c("Sachin","Sachin","Sourav","Sourav","Dravid", "Sehwag", "Dhoni", "Ronin",   "Ronin", "Paul", "jorge", "Anke", "Krystal", "Katy", "Katy","Josh", "Paul"), 
                   idA = c("1234", "1234", "9876", "9876", "3456", "8888", "4032", "1093", "1093", "3452", "3332", "7656", "0023", "4244", "4244","4244","1111"), 
                   idB = c(1,"NA",2,2,3,"NA",5,6,"NA","NA",8,9,10,"NA",11,"NA","NA"), var_a = c(4,5,1.6,4.4,2,2,4,9,2,34,5,6,7,2,0,4,8), var_b = c("d","h","g","w","g","p","ads","f","a","iu","n","lag", "lo", "t", "v","y","k"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


df1 |> mutate(idB = as.numeric(idB)) |> 
  arrange(name,idA,idB) |> 
  group_by(name, idA) |> 
  fill(idB, .direction = "down")
#> Warning: There was 1 warning in `mutate()`.
#> ℹ In argument: `idB = as.numeric(idB)`.
#> Caused by warning:
#> ! NAs introduced by coercion
#> # A tibble: 17 × 5
#> # Groups:   name, idA [13]
#>    name    idA     idB var_a var_b
#>    <chr>   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
#>  1 Anke    7656      9   6   lag  
#>  2 Dhoni   4032      5   4   ads  
#>  3 Dravid  3456      3   2   g    
#>  4 Josh    4244     NA   4   y    
#>  5 Katy    4244     11   0   v    
#>  6 Katy    4244     11   2   t    
#>  7 Krystal 0023     10   7   lo   
#>  8 Paul    1111     NA   8   k    
#>  9 Paul    3452     NA  34   iu   
#> 10 Ronin   1093      6   9   f    
#> 11 Ronin   1093      6   2   a    
#> 12 Sachin  1234      1   4   d    
#> 13 Sachin  1234      1   5   h    
#> 14 Sehwag  8888     NA   2   p    
#> 15 Sourav  9876      2   1.6 g    
#> 16 Sourav  9876      2   4.4 w    
#> 17 jorge   3332      8   5   n

Created on 2024-11-26 with reprex v2.1.1

You might try ave:
> with(df1, ave(strtoi(idB), interaction(name, idA), FUN = \(x) na.omit(x)[1]))
 [1]  1  1  2  2  3 NA  5  6  6 NA  8  9 10 11 11 NA NA

or
library(dplyr)
df1 |>
  mutate(idB=min(idB, na.rm=TRUE), .by=c(name, idA))

